# Why SQL Server Analysis Services Remote Connection work in Excel but not C# Web App

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, mdx, olap, analysisservices

I have a SQL Server Analysis Services Cube published to a remote windows server, not attached to a domain.

I can use use Excel to connect to it remotely by using the wizard at Data -> Get Data -> From Database -> From Analysis Services, and providing a userName and password of a user created on the server for this purpose. It works fine.

I need to connect to the cube with a web app (C#/Blazor). For testing/development, we need to connect from local website running on developer laptops, and well as a separate web servers (not same box as database server).

Tried the following, and many variations:

```
AdomdConnection(@"Data Source=<ip_address>; Catalog=<DB_Name>; User Id=<user>; Password=<user pwd>; Cube=<Cube_Name>; Provider=MSOLAP;");
```

The error message is:

> A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running.
> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..

Since it works in Excel, that should mean there are no firewall or user/pwd issues. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you read through the [Analysis Services client libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/client-libraries) documentation yet? What version of SSAS are you connecting to? What version of the client libraries are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using System.Data.OleDB instead of AdoMD.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).